# Use built-in mic instead of earphone mic on call

Tags: microphone, oneplus, earphone

I have very cheap earphones that have a terrible microphone. My phone's built-in microphone is better. How can I make it so that WhatsApp calls (or regular calls) use my phone's mic, instead of my earphones mic?

I tried looking around, and got pointed to apps such as soundabout, which do not exist anymore.

I'm using OnePlus 7 Pro, Android 12, Oxygen OS 12.1

Answer (score 0):

According to an answer on Quora, you can use Lesser Audio Switch (play store) . Plug in earphones -> Go to the settings of this app -> enable switch microphone ->tap the mic icon in front of speaker icon ->select ‘internal microphone’.